# Indexing into mongoose.model for an array is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've created a simple table (document?) in mongoDB.
I'm using Node and Mongoose to connect to it.

In my method, I am calling `model.find({})` to retrieve all records and then iterating over them to find one that I want (this is within a loop - I'm thinking it will be more efficient to hit the DB once, and then process in memory to avoid connecting to the database each time).

When I `console.log` the match, I'm getting the full object printed out.  When I print out one property, however, it's listing it as undefined.  This property is an array, and it's happening for another property that has an array that I added as a test.  What am I missing here?

Here's my code snippet:

```
 Documents.find({}).then(docsData => { // Documents is my model
      docs.entries.forEach(entry => { // docs.entries is the collection I want to match to
        const match = docsData.find(
          doc => doc['dropboxId'] == entry['id']
        );
        if (match) {

          entry['tags'] = match.tags;
          console.log('match tags', match.tags); // this prints out undefined
          console.log('match', match); // this prints out the object with tags
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try accessing the element with array notation
          console.log('match tags', match["tags"]); // this will prints out

Comment: I have tried that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match` is a Mongoose document which is different from normal JS object. I guess you need to do:

`entry['tags'] = match.get('tags');`

Comment: Thank you!  This is working.  Are you able to point me to the documentation that suggests this?